# Laravel - Routes with "sub" views

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am just getting started with Laravel and find the route setup a little confusing. I am trying to create a few pages, that ultimately should have the struture:

```
domain.com/onboarding
domain.com/onboarding/skip
domain.com/onboarding/skip/anothersubview
```

etc.

Right now I have:

```
// Registered and Activated User Routes
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'activated', 'activity']], function () {

    Route::get('/onboarding', 'UserController@Onboarding')->name('onboarding');
});
```

Would the solution here (and best practice) be to just add another route inside my `Route::group`, like:

```
Route::view('/onboarding/skip', 'onboarding.skip');
```

Is this the correct way of doing things?

Comment: I did it in few projects in the past, I just placed `group` inside of `group` inside of `group` and nothing was wrong, I don't know if it's bad or good habit but every page worked smoothly and everything was fine

Comment: If it's static pages then `Route::view` is probably the best solution. Also best practice is to be explicit with your routes. That way you know what navigates where without any surprises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **prefix** :

```
   Route::group(['prefix' => 'onboarding','middleware' => ['auth', 'activated', 'activity']], function () {

        Route::get('/', 'UserController@Onboarding')->name('onboarding');
        Route::get('/skip', 'UserController@OnboardingSkip')->name('onboarding_skip');
        Route::get('/skip/anothersubview', 'UserController@OnboardingSkipSubview')->name('onboarding_skipsubview');

    });
```

read more here : https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing

Comment: But what if I have other routes inside the `Route::group` that have nothing to do with `/onboarding`

Comment: you need to define separate route , which does not have prefix onboarding

Answer (score 1):

The structure I used in a few projects in the past looks like this:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'onboarding'], function(){
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'something'], function(){
        Route::get('/', function(){}); //onboarding/something
        Route::group(['prefix' => 'somethingelse'], function(){
            Route::get('/', function(){}); //onboarding/something/somethingelse
            Route::get('/{id}', function(){}); //onboarding/something/somethingelse/15
        });
    });
});
```

nesting groups can help you make the easier extendable router because when you realize you need to add some URL in the middle of long structure it would be easier to do it with this concept

Answer (score 0):

You have a web.php file in your routes folder, there you need to add:

```
Route::get('/subpage', 'controllername@function-name-you-want-to-call');
```

Hope this helps, if it doesn't let me know

/e: to clarify:

the first part

> Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'activated', 'activity']], function () {

is the authentication. Depending on who you want to access this page, you might not need it